# OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions azure active directory setting the RedirectUri for different environments

Tags: c#, azure, openid-connect

How do I set the redirectUri for different environments ?  In my development environment I want to return to

https://localhost/

and in my deployed azure version I want to return to

https://appname.portal.p.azurewebsites.net/

In my startup.auth.cs file I have this

```
#if DEBUG
                                       RedirectUri = "https://localhost/",
                #else
                                    RedirectUri = "https://appname.portal.p.azurewebsites.net/",
                                    #endif
```

If I run in release mode it won't work, I enter my username and password and I get

> Bad Request - Request Too Long
>
> HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.

but it works in debug on my local machine

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the web app based on the current HTTP address, we can use the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` like code below:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },        
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
              {
                  string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                  string currentUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path;
                  context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = currentUrl;
                  context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                  return Task.FromResult(0);
              }
        }    
    });
```